# Download mongodb compass and Install Using the Terminal

Tags: ubuntu

I follow the commands based on this link
    https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/install/

```
1. Download the package:
mongodb-compass_1.15.1_amd64.deb 

2. Install Compass:
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.15.1_amd64.deb;

(Reading database ... 195489 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mongodb-compass_1.15.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-compass (1.15.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-compass:
 mongodb-compass depends on libgconf-2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mongodb-compass (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-compass
```

“How to fix ‘Installation’ error in Ubuntu” can anyone help my problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you check you log you will see this error:

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-compass:
>
> mongodb-compass depends on libgconf-2-4; however:   Package
>
> libgconf-2-4 is not installed.

So install libgconf-2-4.

```
apt-get install libgconf-2-4
```

Answer (score 23):

In case there are multiple missing packages

`sudo apt install ...`

will be tedious. After running

`sudo dpkg -i <package-name>`

and getting dependency problems error you can run

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

which will install all missing dependencies and after that running

`sudo dpkg -i <package-name>`

will install your needed package.

Comment: I'd say this is proper answer instead of specifying what to install manually

Comment: Running `sudo apt install <package-name> --fix-broken` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sudo apt install -f` and then `sudo dpkg -i <your file.deb>`

Answer (score 3):

Run the following commands:-

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4
sudo dpkg -i <<your deb package name .deb>>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all, you need to `fix broken installs` by running the flowing command

   `sudo apt --fix-broken install`
2. After that, install `libgconf-2-4`

   `sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4`
3. then install your `.deb` package with the following command

   `sudo dpkg -i <<package_file.deb>>`

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf2-common libgconf-2-4
```